# Why after passing more than 24 hours some tips close button on Polkadot js are still grey/disabled?

Tags: polkadot, polkadot-js, tips

After a treasury tip receives "half + 1" tips from the councils, It goes to the countdown period. I run `api.consts.tips.tipCountdown` on Polkadot an get `14,400`, which should be in blocks! If it is true 14400 equals 24 hours (since the inter-block space is 6 seconds).

Now my question is, If my calculation is true, why after passing more than 24 hours some tips close button on Polkadot js are still grey/disabled?